# What determines who represents a country in the UN after a coup or revolution?

Tags: united-nations, coup, revolutions

Coups and revolutions happen quite often throughout the world. Sometimes the new government gets the UN seat automatically after the events, while in other cases years may pass and a special General Assembly resolution is needed so to transfer the seat to the new regime.

So, my question is: what determines who will possess the UN seat of a country after a coup in absense of any special UN resolutions?

My guesses:

- This depends on the position of the country's ambassador to the UN, if he/she recognizes the new regime, the seat transfer happens smoothly.
- This depends on whether the USA recognizes the new regime, because it is the USA who issues the diplomatic visas to the UN.

Maybe, something else? Were there cases when the US did not recognize a regime but it was represented in the UN and vice versa?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Credentials_Committee

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78074/who-is-supposed-to-be-giving-orders-to-the-remaining-afghan-diplomats-of-the-pre

Comment: @KelvinSherlock that committee creates recommendations for General Assembly.

Comment: @Anixx and that's your answer.  It's decided by the General Assembly vote.

Comment: There's also [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2906/are-there-un-norms-for-a-government-change) on how the UN recognises changes of government.

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31767/how-did-russia-retain-the-unsc-veto-power-of-the-soviet-union